# Replicate elements of a list in an array in R

Tags: arrays, r, list

I am new to this forum and R, so beforehand my apologies if my question is not clear or I don't folllow the 'unwritten rules' of this forum.

I am doing a simulation study in R with a for loop that is running a function several times. I would like to write the results of the function in a list, each time the for loop runs the function. These lists I would like to combine in an array, with dim(x,x,Number of simulations).
I am not sure whether this is the right way to do, basically I am looking for a way to store my X (number of simulations)-lists with results in a handy way in one variable (so I can use this variable as VAR[i] <- function.. in my for loop).

I hope that it is clear what I mean. I think that my example code makes more clear what I am looking for:

Thaks a lot for hints/suggestions/answers of all kind!

```
#These are e.g. the variables I get as output from the function.
a <- matrix(NA, 2,1)
b <- matrix(NA,2,1)
beta <- matrix(NA,2,1) 
bp <- array(NA,c(2,2,2))

#I save these variables in a list (this is done already in the function self)
results <- list(a = a, b = b, beta = beta, bp = bp)

#Now, I would like to create an array to save this list each time I run the 
#function in my for loop. I tried this, but did not succeed: 
results2 <- array(results, c(1,1,10))
results3 <- array(rep(results))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  To answer your first concern, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/faq  .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you might just want to use another list 
to store all the outputs of your function `fun` (as an example I made the return value of the function dependent on the function argument `x`)

```
fun <- function(x){
  ##These are e.g. the variables I get as output from the function.
  a <- matrix(x/2, 2,1)
  b <- matrix(x/2,2,1)
  beta <- matrix(x/2,2,1) 
  bp <- array(x/2,c(2,2,2))
  list(a = a, b = b, beta = beta, bp = bp)
}
```

Then you could use `lapply` which is a wrapper for a for-loop in order to get a list with all your results (here the function is called 100 times):

```
all.results <- lapply(1:100, fun)
```

You can now access the result of each function call with `all.results[[1]]`, `all.results[[2]]` etc.

Alternatively, if you want to use a `for` loop:

```
all.results <- list()
for (i in 1:100){
  all.results[[i]] <- fun(i)
}
```

Does this help?

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! 
That is indeed what I want. However, I need to use a foor loop, because there are other operations I have to perform on the same data in the same loop..

Comment: Thanks! That's indeed what I was looking for.. And I could not figure out what dimensions I had to use for the list, although the solution was so obvious (as you do, just leave the list empty...) Sometimes the most obvious is the hardest to see I guess..
Thanks!